# How to save network settings in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, bash, linux-networking, ip

For example i used next commands:

```
ip address add IP dev interface

IP route add default via IP dev interface
```

and if I reboot Debian then the settings are just reset.
I used command `iptables-save`, it didn't work, it could not save it.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#A3_ways_to_configure_the_network

Comment: `iptables-save` shows the IPTables firewall settings to the screen, it has nothing to do with network interface configuration.

Comment: use /etc/network/interfaces for the network since debian created